# Run VB.NET on Mono

Tags: .net, vb.net, ubuntu, mono

Which version of Mono do I need to convert and run the Windows applications that I developed using VB.NET that came along with .NET 3.5, in Ubuntu?

Comment: __You don't need to recompile your code.__ Just run your app through MOMA, correct any problems and recompile in windows. The compiled assembly should then run fine on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version. Run your applications through [MOMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) (The Mono Migration Analyzer) first though, to find out if your code can work unmodified in a linux environment (things like file paths are completely different and more).

Comment: Can you tell me the version no? Or will giving the command -
sudo apt-get install mono-develop , fetch me the latest version?

Comment: That command will get you the latest version that is packaged by Ubuntu. It should be fine.

Comment: Ubuntu repository contains ver. `2.4.2.3` when the latest is `2.6.3`

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu just use the mono version from the repositories via `apt-get install mono`. Only if this version does not work, search for a repository that gives you an more recent version.

If you just want to run your binaries, you just need mono itself (including the libraries used by your assembly). If you want to convert your code to mono, use MOMA as stated by Oded and work the code over.

Answer (score 1):

`VB.NET` is much less supported by `Mono` then `C#`. Use `MOMA` to find out more concrete information about that. I recommend you rewrite your code onto C# and then port it on Mono. It will bring you much more stable result.

Comment: Mono has a VB compiler and can gun compiled code just fine anyway.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: My experience with `vbc` is far from positive grade. We couldn't port our VB.NET project (~65k strings of code) because of huge amount of unsupported methods and other strange errors