# I want to Run Vb.Net Hello World GUI based application on Linux mono

Tags: .net, vb.net, linux, mono

I am getting below error when I am trying to run vb.net application on Linux through mono.

```
(HelloWorld.exe:965): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /root/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/HelloWorld.exe could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   Microsoft.VisualBasic    (assemblyref_index=1)
     Version:    8.0.0.0
     Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/root/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/).
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably be running the **Release** build of your code, rather than the Debug build.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run VB.NET on Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673903/run-vb-net-on-mono)

Answer (score 1):

Probably proper library is not installed in your system. If you are using ubuntu, try

```
sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc
```

Otherwise search for analogous package for your distribution. You can also compile it from [here](https://github.com/mono/mono-basic).

Comment: That's the running code on windows. Could you please tell me how to compile from above link and specifically tell me what are the package required or lib to run UI based application through mono.I am able to run console based application through mono. I am quite new to Linxu and mono.